# JRE crashes in Eclipse since upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I've been developing Android apps on Eclipse 4.2.2 and Java 1.6.0_21 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS without any problems. Recently I got an upgrade notification for 14.04 and so I upgraded. Now I keep getting the following error in Eclipse

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f90b685a2a1, pid=7131, tid=140264058119936
#
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid7131.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You can't run the JRE you installed in Ubuntu 12.04 in 14.04; you can try to re-install Java 6. Remember that it's no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a solution, which is to add the following line to eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Comment: Thanks - this workaround also works in similar crashes of Crashplan backup client (!) - where it has to be set in 
`./bin/run.conf` under `GUI_JAVA_OPTS=`